# Google softfail when sending between accounts on same domain

Tags: spf

I'm dealing with this for almos a month. Tried several changes but no luck.

Some users manage their e-mail addresses through standard Gmail. **NOT Google Apps**. Their accounts were configured as **aliases**.

Some users manage their e-mail addresses using MSOutlook software.

When USER1 (from outlook client software) sends a message to USER2 (alias on gmail), I get softfail and that message get marked as junk.

Both users have same domain addresses and sending to another domains works ok (not identified as spam by other domains).

On hosting settings I had this TXT

> v=spf1 include:spf.hostmar.com -all

and changed to this:

> v=spf1 ip4:200.58.114.60 include:spf.hostmar.com -all

where 200.58.114.60 is my MX server IP. Not included "mx" into spf as for [this](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes#no-mx).

I checked spf with [kitterman's tool](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html) and it's ok).

Resuming: How can I eliminate softfail error when sending from outlook to other e-mail addresses on same domain? 
If anyone can point me on the right direction I will appreciate.

PS: Sorry if lacks of information, I tried several times to send this but always got a "This looks like SPAM" message and can't send it.

```
Delivered-To: xxxxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.112.91.4 with SMTP id ca4csp2030121lbb;
        Tue, 26 May 2015 11:32:53 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.112.63.201 with SMTP id i9mr23815978lbs.93.1432665172679;
        Tue, 26 May 2015 11:32:52 -0700 (PDT)
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=softfail (google.com: best guess record for domain of transitioning yyyyy@dominguezlab.com.ar does not designate <unknown> as permitted sender) smtp.mail=yyyyy@dominguezlab.com.ar
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: best guess record for domain of transitioning yyyyy@dominguezlab.com.ar does not designate <unknown> as permitted sender)
Received: by 10.112.34.13 with POP3 id v13mf5100257lbi.12;
        Tue, 26 May 2015 11:32:51 -0700 (PDT)
X-Gmail-Fetch-Info: xxxxx@dominguezlab.com.ar 1 mail.dominguezlab.com.ar 110 xxxxx@dominguezlab.com.ar
Return-path: <yyyyy@dominguezlab.com.ar>
Envelope-to: xxxxx@dominguezlab.com.ar
Delivery-date: Tue, 26 May 2015 15:06:59 -0300
Received: from [123.123.123.123] (helo=PC)
    by fiorenza.dattaweb.com with esmtpsa (TLSv1:AES256-SHA:256)
    (Exim 4.77)
    (envelope-from <yyyyy@dominguezlab.com.ar>)
    id 1YxJFi-0007Cr-NO; Tue, 26 May 2015 15:06:59 -0300
From: "YYYYY" <yyyyy@dominguezlab.com.ar>
To: "'XXXXX'" <xxxxx@dominguezlab.com.ar>,
    "'HHHHH'" <hhhhh@dominguezlab.com.ar>,
    <zzzzz@dominguezlab.com.ar>,
    "'MMMMM'" <mmmmm@dominguezlab.com.ar>
Subject: RV: XYZ
Date: Tue, 26 May 2015 15:06:54 -0300
Organization: XYZ
Message-ID: <011901d097de$c0faf330$42f0d990$@com.ar>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_011A_01D097C5.9BADBB30"
X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
X-MSMail-Priority: High
X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0
Thread-Index: AdCX13bKq0tzzNdFRNeXqALiO+XCOgABxTAQ
Content-Language: es-ar
Importance: High
X-Antivirus: avast! (VPS 150526-0, 26/05/2015), Outbound message
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_011A_01D097C5.9BADBB30
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_001_011B_01D097C5.9BADBB30"


------=_NextPart_001_011B_01D097C5.9BADBB30
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: I believe you would need to provide the email headers from a message that went into a junk folder.  That would be more telling of the issues the receiving servers had evaluating the message from your domain.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. First time it didn't let me to add email headers... maybe for being my first post?

Comment: Note: sender yyyyy@dominguezlab.com.ar sends using Outlook to xxxxx, hhhhh, zzzzz and mmmmm. Those four emails are accessed using Gmail.

Comment: This looks like a problem with Google. First, they are not reading your SPF record correctly, though when I looked at your SPF record it looks correct. Second, they did not even read the IP address that they received your mail from correctly! This indicates to me that the problem lies with Google, not with you.

Comment: @dragonauta, you might also want to take a look at [this link](http://serverfault.com/questions/613943/spf-softfail-for-forwarded-emails-to-gmail-account)

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for the link but I think it's not same situation. A user is sending through outlook to same domain, and there's no relay. Google is getting all e-mails through pop3 and that's when this issue occurs. So if a gmail user sends using smtp.dominguezlab.comar to same domain it works ok, but when outlook user sends using smtp.dominguezlab.com.ar to same domain it falls into junk

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton. It's really odd that only occurs with users that uses MS Outlook (they are just 4 users). Any other user (whom uses gmail as a client) don't have this problem. To say: User A access to gmail to sends a mail to user B using my smtp. Then User B access to gmail and check his account (gmail pulls POP3) and get the mail sent by User A into inbox. But when User X using MS Outlook sends a mail to user B (or A or C, whatever) using my smtp, then User B access to gmail and check his account and get the mail sent by X into junk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is it.

Microsoft Outlook is **NOT RFC2821 compliant**.

Gmail expects a valid domain but all that gets it's machine NetBios name.

That's why all e-mail sent using an Outlook client get caught as junk and ends into spam folder.

Solution, use a RFC2821 compliant mail client software.

Thanks to all